# Handling gettext / string translation when WP is installed in subfolder

Tags: translation, plugin-wpml

**My setup**

I have a custom PHP application that uses po/mo files in a locale directory to provide translations for the website strings. All works perfectly. I have Wordpress installed in a sub-directory (/articles). My Wordpress template includes components from the app above it eg:

```
<?php include_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/shared_assets/navigation.php"); ?>
```

**What I tried**

I have installed WPML String Translation. My plan was to scan the theme, and import the po file I already have, but of course the WPML scan cannot "see" the included files from the main app above it. At this point I think I have started down entirely the wrong path.

**My question**

What is the best technique for translating Wordpress templates in a subfolder style installation?

Comment: `po`/`mo` files don't care about the location of the string to be translated, just the WPML string translation tool, most MO/PO files are not created using WPML though so it's utterly irrelevant that your files are in a subfolder style install unless you're insisting on that specific tool, just run the normal tools to generate it on both locations and append one files results to the other, then compile the resulting file. If you are asking specifically about that plugin though then the question needs to be closed as offtopic, 3rd party plugins are offtopic here

Comment: the official WP docs have multiple suggestions here for generating the POT/PO for compilation into an MO file https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/localization/#generating-the-pot-file, PoEdit might be the easiest